# mapping an optional value in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

This answer to this is probably simple, but I just can't find it anywhere!

Lots of languages (i.e. Swift) allow you to .map on an optional type.

i.e. in swift:

```swift
let value: Int? = 1
let doubled = value.map { $0 * 2 }
```

Here, doubled is typed as `Int?`, and contains the double of `value` or undefined, if `value` is undefined.

I can't see a similar thing in typescript?

The best I can do is this

```js
const value: number | undefined = 2;
const double = value !== undefined ? value * 2 : undefined;
```

This looks really clumsy, and doesn't scale well if `value` is a long path into an object.

Is there an easier way in typescript to map a value if it exists, ignoring it if not?

---

EDIT: I know about the null coalescing operator, and it's not quite what I'm after :)

I'd like to see if there is some way of transforming a value if it's not undefined, but is ignored if that value *is* undefined.
Coalescing only works for simple types (like the `number` type in my example, which has mislead people, sorry!) but won't work for more complex types. i.e.

```js
const value: Date | undefined = <a date, maybe>
const adjusted = value ? performComplexDateOperation(value) : undefined;
```

---

EDIT (2)

Via @vr.'s comment, this might be the best solution?

```js
function map<A, B>(value: A | undefined, f: (value: A) => B): B | undefined {
  if (value === undefined) return undefined;
  return f(value);
}
```

used like:

```js
const value: Date | undefined = <a date, maybe>
const adjusted = map(value, date => performComplexDateOperation(date));
```

Comment: `const value: number? = 2` doesn't look like valid TypeScript to me.  Can you test out your code in an IDE to make sure you provide a [mre]?

Comment: @jcalz It is in fact wrong. I made sure to correct him in my answer

Comment: I don't see anything quicker since numbers don't have a map method anyway.  If you want to optionally call an actual method then you can do so like `value?.toFixed(1)`, which produces `"2.0"` or `undefined`.  But there's no postfix "perform operation on this value" for random things in JS, so I'm not sure how to improve it.

Comment: Sigh, that was from the Swift - sorry! I've corrected my question :)

Comment: This should really be a question about JavaScript. TypeScript doesn't try to add new features to the language (besides enums and class property initializer shorthand). Anyways, I would just create a helper function. `map(value, (v) => v * 2)` - Not pretty, but it would work. In any case, I would stick to ternaries.

Comment: If you're willing to use external libraries, you can use one that emulates the behavior of `Option` in other languages (i.e. fp-ts).

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way to do this but if `value` is a long path in an object, then your solution will be long anyways.

This is called the [Null Coalescing Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing).

You simply put: `{value} ?? {default_value}`

In your case:

```js
const value: number | undefined = 2
const double = (value ?? null) * 2
```

**EDIT: As @jcalz mentioned, the result of `double` is `0`.**

If you want the result to be `"undefined"` then you should use the following:

```js
const double = value ? value * 2 : undefined
```

---

> **Note:** You cannot use `{type}?` as a nullable type when declaring a variable using `const`.
>
> ```js
> // Invalid code
> const value: number? = 2;
>                    ^
> ```

Comment: Hahaha... You're almost correct. `2 * undefined` is equal to `NaN`. But `2 * null` is equal to 0

Comment: but either way, that's not what the OP wants; it should be `undefined`, not `0` or `NaN`.  Not sure why you're putting `null` in there anyway.  This answer scares me.

Comment: Okay, i'll modify it

Comment: Hey, sorry, I've updated my question. I know about the `??` and while it works (kind of) in my example, my real use-case is more complicated. I've added a more complicated example to the question to show what I mean.

Comment: In your edit, you said that null coalescing doesn't work for complex types. **That is absolutely incorrect.** Null coalescing works for any and all data types. The solution you chose basically just answered the question: "How do I write an If statement in JavaScript"